# Expanding a modular space-station for 100 years

Tags: space, engineering, space-constructs, construction

The [Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir), [ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station), [Tiangong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_space_station), [Skylab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab), the numerous [Salyut-missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salyut_programme)...Space-stations are one of the most impressive and interesting feats of modern engineering, which in my opinion, makes it even more tragic to see them burn up in the atmosphere at the end of their lives.

And my current setting (an earth-analog) features them as well, with quite a few space-stations in orbit at once during any given period. And for motivations that would take a bit too long to explain (and which don't have much to do with this question), these people don't plan on letting their stations re-enter for a *very* long time. Instead, the engineers of this world set their sights on expanding the preexisting stations by attaching new modules (or possibly combining them with other stations already in orbit) for the duration of their stays, which will be a bit more than a whole century.

Their technological level isn't really progressing all too much during this time, they have roughly the same know-how as we do today.

Which would lead me to my question:

**Could it be possible for a modular space-station to remain structurally stable for over a hundred years, while continuously being added-to?** (and how big could it possibly get?)

Comment: Just as an aside, Stephenson's _Seveneves_ does something like this.  The time scales are different, and (at the beginning anyway) the technology neither improves nor gets replaced.  (*Why not* is a matter of spoilers.)

Comment: Can you say why there might be a problem? Even if you kept the original workings as part of the expanded structure, why should that be a problem? If you added new parts in one direction and dropped off older components in the other, why would there be a problem?

Comment: Isn't this basically the intro of Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, via Ship of Theseus

This is very easy to accomplish. Over time, as components are added and expanded, outdated or worn out components are replaced by their equivalents. If the station has been designed in a modular way, I see no reason this shouldn’t be possible.

At any given time, no part of the station would be older than the maximum shelf life of modules in your world (ten years? Twenty years?) but the station as a whole can be arbitrarily old as a whole.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149092/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-b-expanding-a-modular-space-station-for-100-years); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The Golden Gate Bridge was started in 1937, is built of steel, and spans a stretch of environment that is almost completely inhospitable to steel. Yet it will certainly last for at least 100 years The secret to its sustainability is that it is continually being painted, The process has never stopped. As the paint wears off, due to environmental factors, it is replaced. A central spine linking current and future modules could likewise be built to endure the ravages of Earth's upper atmosphere, if it were coated with tiles or such that are continuously replaced in an ongoing maintenance process.

Answer (score 4):

**Maybe**

(The third possible answer other than No and Yes by others)

The primary reason of current stations failing is that the modules, including air locks and outside insulation, gather micro-damage originated from high energy particles or specks of dust colliding at high speeds. We here do not have the tech required to provide preemptive sealing ability to the pressurized compartment, and employing structure scanning aboard is apparently difficult enough to perform a complete scan of the space station, or even a single module. The secondary reason is that computers evolve, and what was a decent computing power brought to orbit in 2000, does not just count for 2020.

If, however, your world's space industry would froze their standards for space station elements for a century (which is largely impossible here on Earth, for numerous reasons starting with f'n copyright), then a space station might be operational as a whole by gradually replacing modules that are on the brink of failure, or have just outlived their usage, with freshly made identical systems, and maintaining redundancy all the time. But, since replacing a module in the midst of a space station would require undocking both sides thus disconnecting the SS in two or more, there have to be elements in its construction devised for at least temporary connection of separated parts of it during replacement operation. Like, if you are to replace the ISS's *Destiny* module, you would need a connection of all that's behind it to the bulk of the station, such technologies need to exist and be reliably adapted to space-based installments before such station would be able to last for this long.

Yes, the station would be like Ship of Theseus, eventually getting all its parts replaced several times each, but with proper tech and planetside desire to *plan* for a hundred years long space mission it would be possible to maintain. However, it takes much to even start, to my knowledge, ISS was built with some but not all tech required to last a hundred years in orbit, including edge module replacement ability and technology, at least one airlock module was replaced during its flight, and we already run it with state-of-the-art tech, so maybe... MAYBE we would build a station designed to eventually get fully replaced in orbit. Before that, we're doomed to bury our space experiments once in a while, and your people are too.

**How big it can be - well, BIG**

If you're totally into module-based construction for a space station, with a means of replacing any single module at one time, I say you can build at least ten times bigger station than ISS, both dimensions-wise and pressured volume-wise. Eventually you'll hit limits of energy supply (aka no more place for solar batteries, as energy demand would rise as volume while energy supply would rise as square, limits of resource supply as increased space would require increased crew thus increased demand on *everything*, and limits on building new parts as having more parts in the station means more replacement parts need making and delivering them to orbit. This would equalize somewhere above the current state of ISS, depending on technology used at every stage of module and rocket production (QA for each module would be a major issue), thus putting a feasibility and sustainability limit on the size of your station.

Comment: There are quite a few technologies that we've known about and even worked on since the 70's and 80's, like modular nuclear reactors or spirulina-alga-cultures for food and oxygen-production, so the resource availability could scale a bit better than what we've currently *built* in our world, even if we currently have the plans and means, though i haven't really thought about the fact that a bigger station will need more parts for repairs, seems really damn obvious now that i think about it :p

Comment: if each module comes with its own power and station keeping unit and there's a rigorous growth typology such as docking them one after the other,building a giant snake around the planet, then power/volume would grow linearly too, imo

Comment: @jkztd an interesting idea, needs thorough consideration. It has some advantages for such a purpose, a snake can always drop its old tail off and get new stuff as head. Acceleraing it to not let it fall would also be doable from the head (snake flies tail first, hehe), although mass center would have to be adjusted for correct momentum transfer. Yet IIRC a long chain in space tends to turn vertically due to gravity force difference, maybe this is the reason ISS was not a snake. Sounds working in fact!

Comment: @Vesper that is why I mentioned individual station keeping ability for each module, so that they actively avoid aligning along gravity gradient, and can occupy the intended orbital path even if the snake is "segmented" at some point in building or servicing

Comment: @jkztd this means each of your modules is essentially an *independent space station*, with all elements like life support, power generation, maneuver engines, airlocks (these are mandatory anyway), space toilets etc? Isn't it superfluous? Space delivery still measures kilograms of mass when selecting cargo, I doubt whoever would govern making that station would let in several redundant modules. Two, maybe three, the rest should be not as independent. And here we get issues...

Comment: Re max size: local differences in gravity do not ever become a problem? No matter just how big you let it grow, no matter how many moons, mountains/valleys and local differences in material composition the orbited planet has?

Comment: @Sixtyfive not enough data. At least you might be pretty sure that building a space station of 1 km long is possible. More - issues may arise, but you are more likely to hit acceleration issues (speeding up along the orbit to raise it, to combat orbital decay) with a station this long than with gravity. IMHO.

Comment: I see, makes sense. And you will _want_ it long and wide and flat to optimise solar-power-area vs. station-volume ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so maybe?

As other post have pointed out, the structure will eventually just wear out either from high speed space dust or thermal expansion contraction over time. Micro stresses will build up.

You can get around this. BUT it will cost you dearly and be highly inefficient. Buildings especially built today are seemingly built as disposable structures like a Bic Razor. If today you live in the US in a neighborhood, that was built in say the 1920s-30's. they would be considered historic. In England 21% of homes were built before 1919. Edwardian era and even Tudor homes are not uncommon.  The Hagia Sophia Mosque in Turkey is over 1600 years old built in the year 360, There are many other older buildings still in use, and not completely replace as per "Ship of Theseus"

Obviously building a cathedral in space out of monolithic stones is absurde.
With our current tech as OP stated is the setting, it becomes even more unlikely. But perhaps fortune may smile upon the the station builders and provide them with a serendipitous source of building material they do not have to hoist up though the planetary gravity well. If this were an alternate earth, I would say relocating the asteroid Psyche to earth orbit and redefining it as our second moon (Would we still call the moon Moon if we had two?). Psyche is
roughly ~270km in diameter and of mostly nickel iron composition. With this source of virtually unlimited material, you could convince me that a determined mind could build orbital structures that could last long enough to satisfy the OPs requirements.

Alternatively: Rather the the whole of the stations being designed to last this long. What if we designed and built only the frameworks to be 'permanent' and even made in a way to be connected to other frames in a modular way. Components that the individual frames contained could be replaced as time wore them down or they became obsolete. From a distance the structure would look the same. Only on closer inspection would one notice the new recent additions. Like walking into the Notre-Dame Cathedral rebuilt after the fire to see this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are good answers out there, but one must remember the issue of micrometeorites and space debris. With a technology roughly as that of ours, there would be some challenges. The analogy of the ship of Theseus proposed by Daniel B is a good workaround. Unlike building on Earth, where gravity puts stress on the modules, in space it is basically the act of docking and un-docking which may pose a temporary stress. Micrometeorites do not necessarily puncture the hull from the first hit, but eventually they will cause damage and chipping off the hull's surface. Expansion and contraction due to heat difference between sunlit and shaded parts of the hull can put stress on clamping areas between the modules. There may be more "wear and tear" factors I didn't think about, but I think cosmic rays may cause some metal fatigue over time. In addition, spin-gravity for the comfort of astronauts may add the stress of centrifugal force which is comparable to gravity on Earth. Can a ship dock while the station is spinning? What will be the effect of change in the weight distribution? Replacing a module would require temporarily stopping the spin. If space stations are small enough, it may be a good idea to launch a new one instead. Much larger stations would benefit from the modular approach. There are also the orbital corrections. Low Earth Orbie (LEO) exposes the station to atmospheric drag from the exosphere. This is "orbital decay". You need to take higher orbits if you want the station to last longer. And each time a ship docks or undocks, there is always a slight "push" or "pull" while docking, which may change orbit. So orbital correction may be necessary. Thrusters must be placed correctly and expanding the station may require changing their layout or adding more thrusters. Thrust adds stress on the structure and an old station in need of maintenance may rip apart.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

I own a hundred-year-old building and am currently adding onto it. It's expanding the usability of the building, but one absolute truth remains...

... The original building is on its last legs and will eventually (sooner rather than later) be demolished due to increasing decay, aging infrastructure, and all the safety problems that come with it. And that's ignoring the reality that it's more expensive to maintain an old building than a new one.

Now add the pain of sending those extensions into orbit.

I know you said that the technology level isn't progressing much — but that's a fallacy. Technology progresses as problems are solved, and an ongoing space program that's valuable enough to justify sending extensions and modifications into orbit can't possibly mean there are no problems to solve. You have at least those relating to aging structures, aging infrastructure, and the natural inclination for someone to stub their proverbial toe on something that doesn't work in your, let's say, 50-year-old space station and say, "there's got to be a better way to do this."

So, technology isn't quite as stagnant as you might think. Not replacing or maintaining the space stations represents stagnation.

**Why doesn't this work?**

Earth has a remarkable advantage over space. If I want to add on to an old building, I simply clear the weeds, lay some concrete, and (OK, simplistically) nail some wood together. You see, it's not really the old building I'm adding onto. Oh, I might be using one of its walls (compared to constructing an entirely new building), but the simple truth is, I'm building something on the surface of the planet. I need to worry *a lot less* (if at all) about the connection to the old building. Yup, I'm oversimplifying, but think of it this way...

...that space station might have been designed for extensibility, but 100 years is forever in technology years, and the cost of putting a space station into orbit that can be arbitrarily extended and/or modified...

Take it from an engineer. We're mortal. We can't see that far into the future and plan for every contingency. That space station must handle 100% of the new add-on (power, utilities, structural strength, orbital stability, changes in purpose...), and that's a big deal.

**Conclusion**

So, no, you can't *in real life* do what you're trying to do.

**Epilogue**

Now forget everything I just said. When you write your story, drop a line that basically says, "government engineers, contrary to normal government expectations, successfully designed space stations that can be extended with an unlimited lifespan." Then flip us all the proverbial bird and write your story.

On your world, this isn't just possible. It's practical.

Comment: It's a good answer, though I feel like the main factor that points against the expansion, adding newer modules onto the older stations, is an issue if technology progresses, which in this scenario, it doesn't. I recognize what you said about problem-solving, though in this case it's less about that "i *think* technology *might* not progress much" and more of a "due to some circumstances, it definitely doesn't progress much for the next century.". Repairing existing technology with existing methods is stagnant, but wouldn't really stand int the way of maintenance in my opinion.

Comment: @NimRad There is no example in human history that supports your idea. There is an idea in fiction: L. Ron Hubbard's *Battlefield Earth.* The Psychlos had stagnant technology. They never added onto anything. When it degraded and died, they simply replaced it with *the very same thing.* There was no change - but you're expecting change. You're changing the space stations. Changing purposes, adding new to degrading old, accomodating changes in power and orbit... every problem that must be solved advances technology.

Comment: you're still making quite a few assumptions. Both that the people in question are humans, which otherwise wouldn't really play a bigger part in the question, and that the station's functionality/purpose and orbit get altered in some dramatic way with each addition. The question really is only about structural stability of a modular station itself, as i wrote it.

Comment: @NimRad When it comes to rationalizing an answer, we work with what we have. If you believe I'm making too many assumptions, why'd you bother asking the quesiton? Just move forward with your project. Note that while assuming humanity is certainly true, assuming a dramatic change of purpose with each addition is not. Over a century, expansions will beg a change in purpose (more dynamic technology). Having said that, my answer per infrastructure stands. Nope. Won't work. Ignore that anyway and write a good story.

Comment: IMHO this house analogy falls flat. A) if your house is derelict after 100 years it was either a shoddy build or not well looked after. Where I live there are cities of 100-200+ year old houses and they are doing just fine if you look after them. B) houses are not made in a modular expandable way. The space station is. C) If you have a modular space station no single part needs to be 100 years old (see the ship of Theseus answer above).

Comment: @fgysin (a) I didn't say house, I said building. Building quality and codes vary all over the place, but one thing I have done, I have tried to install electricity into a house that's 100 years old. You obviously haven't. Maybe you should talk to people who own such old buildings and ask them how fine they're really doing - especially when it comes to heating them. (b) See the concluding paragraph in my answer. (c) If the Ship of Theseus answer were valid, why have all our space stations to date been allowed to fall from the sky?

Comment: "That space station must handle 100% of the new add-on" - why? The add-on itself can be self-sustaining. There's no reason the new modules must draw any resources at all from the original station, or have anything other than a physical connection to the station.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie You've not thought this through from an engineering perspective. Unless the "add on" isn't actually an add-on, but a second station in a nearby orbit, it's attached to the original. Everything is attached to the original. With each add-on (self sustaining or not) the stress on the first component grows - assuming it was ever expected to handle all the add-ons (no godlike space stations here, mate. All materials and designs have very real limits).

Comment: Same problem with the Monadnock Building, which is made out of granite and has sunk 20" into the ground. Who's paying to *keep* this thing in orbit? Do none of these answers talk about having to boost it back up where it was? "Where I live there are cities of 100-200+ year old houses and they are doing just fine if you look after them." Yeah, stuff in Europe is *built out of stone*. 'Sticks and paper' don't last so long but sure are cheaper to 'put up'. +1

Comment: The new add-on has to handle *110%* of the *station*. You, your stuff, and it worth coming out here, otherwise we'll all be back real soon.

Comment: there it is : "orbital stability" (100yo buildings usually violate modern set-back requirements. You don't knock them down because you can't put them back. *Even in the future building regulations suck!*)

Comment: @Mazura re sustaining the station in orbit, this is *implied*, as routine expenses on all the stations that were in operation in here. The TS's station would also need to be retained in orbit, or put at a decently higher orbit, based on the planet's atmosphere, but technical expenses of doing so are out of the question's scope.

Comment: @JBH The answer asked about whether it is possible to build a modular, expandable space station which could exist for 100 years continuously. I argue that yes, it is _possible_ (note that the ISS is already 25 years old...). Does it make economic sense? Hell no! But then again, NO space stations make economic sense. Neither does going to the Moon (let alone Mars). We do it because of science, and because _we can_. Providing believable arguments as to _why_ anyone would still expand and upkeep a rickety 100 year old station is something OP/the author needs to do, but is IMHO another question.

Comment: @JBH You design the add-on modules so they fit the station. Some of the modules can add power, some can add life support, some can add structural reinforcement. I see no reason why additional modules must *weaken* the station. You could imagine a large module that simply encapsulates the original station like a nesting doll. You don't need to add modules in an increasingly precarious conga line that's attached to the original station by the original screws it was designed with.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Unless add-ons are very infrequent, they add stress to a station that's weakening daily due to radiation exposure, tension caused by thruster corrections and simply the fact that whatever's closer to the planet tends to want to move more quickly (though just slightly) than what's further away, etc. As I keep telling people, if NASA could simply extend rather than replace a space station... they would. Maybe someday we'll learn how to do it - but even then there are limits. It can't be unplanned or infinite. Otherwise the newer sections simply rip away from the 100 y.o. sections.

Comment: @JBH The ISS has had modules added to it continuously for the last 25 years. I'm perplexed at the view that expanding a space station can't be done - it *has* been done, just not on a 100-year timescale. Until recently, the preferred solution has been to expand the existing ISS rather than launch a new station.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie [According to NASA, age is doing a number on the space station](https://www.inverse.com/science/nasa-kill-iss). The ISS was intentionally designed for each and every module that's been added to it. It's not been ad-hoc and it won't go on forever. It's original lifespan was only 15 years (and then it would have been obliterated), but it's doing well enough that NASA has extended that to 2031. In 2031, the station will be obliterated. Humanity has never launched a space station that could (or should) be arbitrarily expanded and none that have ever had a 100 year life span.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Again from that same article, "In recent years, there’s been an abundance of safety concerns on the ISS. Ranging from mysterious holes to leaky modules...." Unless we assume a (fundamentally) godlike superstructure, time will eventually degrade anything we put in space for the reasons I've already mentioned. It's that degradation that's the problem. That - and the fact that you can't actually replace the superstructure without taking everything apart - which is why it's cheaper to simply send up a new one.

Comment: Yet the Eiffel Tower, built in 1887, is still standing strong.  And the water pistons that move the elevators up and down are still functioning as intended, no electrical motor necessary. Kept very well greased. However, there are some that will proclaim that the only thing keeping it up is the thick coating of paint that has been added to it every year. It's all about the maintenance budget.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond The Eiffel Tower is not exposed to hard radiation and has support struts hundreds of times bigger than anything you'd find on a space station. Those pistons have regular maintenance that's more difficult in space. If the maintenance budget is greater than the cost of sending a new one up (which has been the case in *every case in human history to date,* why would anybody try to maintain an existing station?

Comment: For the same reason the Golden Gate Bridge and the Eiffel Tower are maintained - there is an abundance of economic value to keep them maintained. The economic return exceeds the maintenance costs. ISS returns no economic value, thus no incentive to maintain it.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Economic return is irrelevant. When the cost of maintenance exceeds the cost of inserting a new station, a new station will be inserted unless the OP chooses to ignore economics. 100 years of only adding modules? I've debated before, what happens when the first one breaks beyond repair? Rats, can't maintain it anymore....

Comment: That is the verbosity that economists spout, and Engineers parrot, but the real truth is, no company manager up to the 70's and80's  follows that adage, and it was the period of one of the largest expansions of American industrial production. All maintenance eventually exceeds the cost of replacement over the lifetime of the machine., therefore every machine should be replaced before it is even in production. What is ignored in that directive is the time factor.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond If we're down to tossing insults at one another, then the conversation's value has been exhausted. You're welcome to write your own answer. Every answer is a benefit to both the OP and others who might be interested in the potential value of the question.

Comment: I apologize if what I said comes across as an insult, particularly an insult directed towards you. I have engineering training, and have heard that phrase 'When the cost of maintenance exceeds the cost of replacement, then replace' more than I care to. It is, in my opinion, over simplified and over used. My point is, maintenance is an economic consideration,  Not maintaining something will lead to premature replacement, continuous and effective maintenance can prolong the lifespan of any engineering accomplishment. The Eiffel Tower was originally meant to last only 20 years, then torn down.

Comment: But with continuous maintenance, and providing a continued economic return as a broadcasting tower and tourist spot to justify and cover the cost of maintenance, it has lasted for over 100 years. But if it is torn down, it will not be replaced by anything close to its current form. Or not, considering the controversy over the rehabilitation of the Notre Dame Cathedral. I suggest the answer depends far more on emotional considerations than economic. As regards any heritage building, the symbolic and historical value justifies the maintenance costs.

Comment: The longer ISS stays up there, the stronger the motivation to keep it up, if for nothing more than the historic heritage emotional factor, regardless of the economic cost.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond [NASA plans to obliterate the ISS in 2031](https://www.inverse.com/science/nasa-kill-iss). "However, according to NASA, age is doing a number on the space station. In recent years, there’s been an abundance of safety concerns on the ISS."

Comment: The biggest safety concern on the ISS are the Russians and the Russian module. They can not evict the module, as it is now integral to the ISS performance. So, they destroy the entire station. However, it is not politically correct for the Americans to acknowledge this. However, China might purchase the module from the Russians, and then we see politics like it has never been before.

Answer (score 0):

Making this easy would require completely linear design with new modules being added to the tip and old modules discarded from the base. However such design may not be otherwise optimal (everything is further to reach than with branched design).

With the current stations like ISS, this rule has not been followed. The station branches into multiple directions, so that if you want to replace the ageing Zarya FGB (first module), this cannot be done without disassembling all station into 3 parts that later may be too heavy to navigate and safely attach to the replacing module.

Answer (score 0):

> which in my opinion, makes it even more tragic to see them burn up in
> the atmosphere at the end of their lives.

That line pretty much sums it up.

Give this problem to an engineer, and they will reject it over the more 'practical' solution of continuous replacement and upgrade. That, after all, is what technological advancement is all about, and that is what currently drives space exploration. 'The next venture will be bigger and netter than the last.' Continuous advancement and improvement. Everything is, in the end, just a prototype for the next iteration. They even designed CERN to be replaced/rebuilt.

Give this problem to an architect, on the other hand, and they will say 'Absolutely, my magnificent design just HAS to last a century, for future generations to marvel at'. Architects design monuments to their creativity, to last forever. They do not design to have it crash and burn. Artists, however, are a different creature - Burning Man as a prime example.

It is the emotional piece that the engineer misses, and the architect embodies. A lasting legacy, not just a technological accomplishment.

The Engineer/Scientist says 'why bother?' but the Architect replies 'heritage'.

To keep a space station up for a century is an economic consideration, not an engineering one. Primarily, the cost of continuous maintenance. The Eiffel Tower was designed and intended to last only twenty years, that was the original requirement. It was designed to be torn down, bolted, not welded connections. (In fact, there was some consideration to dismantling it and bringing it to Canada, rebuilding it in Montreal for Expo '67.) Yet over 100 years later, it is still standing. However, the cost of maintaining it is not trivial. After being completely repainted 19 times (with primarily lead paint) the weight of the paint is now 25% of the original weight of the pig iron used to construct it.

This station could, for example (taking a page from the space shuttle design), have a central spline covered in replaceable ceramic tiles meant to be continuously replaced. How long it was kept up in orbit would be a political/economic factor of how motivated the powers that be are in providing the ongoing funding for maintenance. The longer it is intended to remain, the more inventive can be the solutions to build in permanence. These tiles could also incorporate insulation that kept the heat uniform around the outside, preventing expansion and cooling problems. Expansion joints could do the rest. (The Eiffel Tower was designed so that, when the iron side that faced the sun heated up and expanded differentially from the shadow side, the tower would bend to accommodate.) It would, of course, require booster propulsion to keep the orbit stable, or even to lift it into higher orbit as the mass increases.

So the answer depends on whether this is 'just' an engineering/scientific project, or does it have some symbolic nationalistic or corporate goodwill significance? Do they WANT it to last a century, economics be damned, regardless of the functionality or practicality?

There is the old tale about Paul Bunyan's Ax. The original ax is in the Smithsonian, and still in constant use. Mind you, the handle has been replaced ten times, and the head eight, but it is still the 'original' ax.

If economics, cost-benefit, and functional return on investment are disregarded, and the solution desired is an architectural one rather than engineering, the answer becomes **'probably, depending on your budget.'**